# How to center values in stackbar plot and add greek text to legend with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, stackedbarseries

I have created a stacked-bar plot with 'ggplot' to display my karyotype (molecular) results from a transplant experiment, with each panel representing a location, and the x-axis is the various substrates, while the y-axis is the percentage of each of the three karyotypes.

I have looked over several examples of questions and answers from Stack Overflow and cannot figure out how to do the following:

1. centre the values (should be rounded to two decimal places) within each section of the stacked bars, right now I just have them offset from the top.
2. how to change my legend text from "BB" to the Greek "lower alpha, lower alpha", "BD" to Greek "lower alpha, lower beta", and "DD" to Greek "lower beta, lower beta".

Here is some sample data and code with a copy of the plot it generates.

```
Karotype.Data <- structure(list(Location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Kampinge", "Kaseberga", "Molle", "Steninge"), class = "factor"), Substrate = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Kampinge", "Kaseberga", "Molle", "Steninge"), class = "factor"), Karyotype = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("", "BB", "BD", "DD"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Location", "Substrate", "Karyotype"), row.names = c(135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 330L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 430L), class = "data.frame")

z.counts <- Karotype.Data %>% 
  group_by(Location,Substrate,Karyotype) %>% 
  summarise(Frequency=n()) 

z.freq <- z.counts %>% filter(Karyotype != '') %>% 
  group_by(Location,Substrate) %>% 
  mutate(Percent=Frequency/sum(Frequency))
z.freq

ggplot(z.freq, aes(x=Substrate, y=Percent, fill=Karyotype )) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Percent), size = 5, vjust = 1, position = "stack") +
  facet_wrap(~ Location, ncol=2) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Percentage") + 
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(colour="black", size=20, face="bold"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(colour="black", size=20, face="bold", vjust=-0.5),
        axis.text.x  = element_text(colour="black", size=18),
        axis.title.y = element_text(colour="black", size=20,face="bold",  vjust=1),
        axis.text.y  = element_text(colour="black", size=18),
        legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=20, face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size = 18),
        legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add greek letters to the legend, you can change the colour scale with scale_colour_manual():

```
test = data.frame(x=1:30,y=1:30,label=rep(c("BB","BD","DD"),each=10))
ggplot(test) + geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y,color=label)) + scale_colour_manual(values=c(1,2,3),breaks = c("BB","BD","DD"),labels = list(bquote(alpha~alpha),bquote(alpha~beta),bquote(beta~beta)))
```

argument `values` sets the colour, `breaks` sets your breakpoints (BB, BD and DD) and `labels` sets the greek letters you want.

To round the legend, you can add another column to your dataframe, setting values to round(Percent,digits=3), and use this column in the geom_text.

Informations concerning greek letters in ggplot2 can be found [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Plotmath)